# XSLT transform single attribute to element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform single attribute to an element.
The XSL I use is :

```
   <xsl:template match="TextView/@*">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
```

my xml:

```
    <TextView
     android:id="@+id/ti"
     style="@style/HTxt"
     android:text="@string/ti"
     custom:attribute="name" />
```

The above XSL transforms all the attributes to elements. But I want to transform only the 'custom:attribute' and ignore the others. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replaced `@*` with `@custom:attribute`
Therefore try:

```
<xsl:template match="TextView/@custom:attribute">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

**But attention**: `custom` is a [namespace prefix](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-prefix). You have to add it with the same namespace URL as in your XML to your xsl:stylesheet.
Something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
       xmlns:custom="CUSTOM_URL"
    version="1.0">
```

Comment: hr_117 Thank you..But even the other attributes are displayed..how can I remove everything except for custom:attribute ???

Comment: I assume you have a identity transfer template in your xslt. Therefore ads a new template to ignore attributes of TextView (`<xsl:template match="TextView/@*" />`)

Comment: @hr_117 note that you'll need to add explicit `priority="..."` to both templates, as `TextView/@custom:attribute` and `TextView/@*` have the same priority by default.